# How to pull name and background color of each item

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to pull the name and background color of each item in a pyqt5 listbox. My idea was to loop through indexing the row to select one row at a time and pull the name and background color in rgb. I cant seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Below is the incorrect code I have so far: Thanks in advance.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QListWidgetItem, 
import sys

lst_labels = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
lst_labels.setObjectName("lst_labels")
lst_labels.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
item=QListWidgetItem('first')
item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(255,0,0))            
lst_labels.addItem(item)
item=QListWidgetItem('second')
item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(0,255,0))            
lst_labels.addItem(item)
item=QListWidgetItem('third')
item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(0,0,255))            
lst_labels.addItem(item)


for i in range (0,lst_labels.count()):
    lst_labels.SelectRows(i)
    item=lst_labels.selectedItems()

    name=item.text()
    r=item.background().red()
    g=item.background().green()
    b=item.background().blue()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    lst_labels.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I added a minimal example.  The for loop is where my problem is I cant figure out how to select an item and pull the data from the item.

Comment: Why do you want to select an item ?, to obtain the information of an item it is not necessary to select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain the information of each item it is not necessary to select it, you just have to iterate over the items using the item() method:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    lst_labels = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    lst_labels.setObjectName("lst_labels")
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem("first")
    item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(255, 0, 0))
    lst_labels.addItem(item)
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem("second")
    item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(0, 255, 0))
    lst_labels.addItem(item)
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem("third")
    item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(0, 0, 255))
    lst_labels.addItem(item)

    for i in range(lst_labels.count()):
        it = lst_labels.item(i)
        name = it.text()
        brush = it.background()
        color = brush.color()
        print(name)
        print(color.red(), color.green(), color.blue())

    lst_labels.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If instead you want to get the items that the user selects then use the itemSelectionChanged signal and the selectedItems() method:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    lst_labels = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    lst_labels.setObjectName("lst_labels")
    lst_labels.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem("first")
    item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(255, 0, 0))
    lst_labels.addItem(item)
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem("second")
    item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(0, 255, 0))
    lst_labels.addItem(item)
    item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem("third")
    item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor.fromRgb(0, 0, 255))
    lst_labels.addItem(item)

    def on_itemSelectionChanged():
        for it in lst_labels.selectedItems():
            name = it.text()
            brush = it.background()
            color = brush.color()
            print(name)
            print(color.red(), color.green(), color.blue())

    lst_labels.itemSelectionChanged.connect(on_itemSelectionChanged)

    lst_labels.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ah so i didn't even need to select them. Thanks I've had a mental block on this all day.